# Setting cache timeout to a key in Codeigniter using predis package

Tags: php, codeigniter, redis, predis

In Codeigniter, I've installed predis package using Composer. I'm able to set and get the value from cache using this package. My requirement is I need to keep the value in cache using `Redis` for 1 min. I have seen different options setting through `Redis` Terminal. But I need to set the time limit in controller Itself. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `EXPIRE` through predis:

```
$client = new Predis\Client();
$client->set('foo', 'bar');
$client->expire('foo', 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one command:

```
$client = new Predis\Client();
$client->set($key, $value, 'ex', 60);
```

But for maximum performance you should use phpredis extension, not predis library.